The authors' address appears above the title
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal Name}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{truetype}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{pifont,color,multicol}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mwe} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}  % loads »blindtext« and »graphicx«
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}
%\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
%#############################################################################
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\newcounter{myfn}[page]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

\topmargin -0,75in \textheight 9,5 in
\oddsidemargin -0.1in \textwidth 6.5in
\evensidemargin -0.5in \footskip .5in
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

\def\Proof.{{\bf{Proof. }}}
\def\End{\hspace{1cm} $\Box$\\}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\def\Proof.{{\bf{Proof. }}}
\def\End{\hspace{1cm} $\Box$\\}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newfont{\bb}{msbm10 scaled\magstep1}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mbox{\bb N}}
\newcommand{\bZ}{\mbox{\bb Z}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\mbox{\bb Q}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mbox{\bb R}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frontmatter}
        
        \title{\bf \LARGE{XXXXXXXXXXX}}
        
        \def\correspondingauthor{\footnote(Corresponding author: XXXXXX}
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\ast{}$}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \def\correspondingauthor{\footnote(Corresponding author:XXXXXX}
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\ast{}$}
        
        \author{XXXX $^{a,}$
            \footnote{Corresponding author Email address: XXXXXX)}}
        
        \author{XXXXX $^{a,}$
            \footnote{Corresponding author Email address:
            XXXXXXX}}
        \author{ XXXXX $^{a}$}
        \author{ XXXXX $^{b, c}$}
    
        \ \\
        {\footnotesize\it $^{a}$ Department of Mathematical Sciences}
        \\
        {\footnotesize\it $^{b}$ Institute for Mathematical Research}
        \\
        {\footnotesize\it $^{c}$ Department of Mathematics and Statistics}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{abstract}
            ..........
            
            \indent   
        \end{abstract}
        \begin{keyword}
            ........
        \end{keyword}
        
    \end{frontmatter}
    
\end{document}



This is elsevier format

\title, \author, etc. do not print anything, but define material to be printed at \end{frontmatter}., But your pseudo-footnotes using {\footnotesize\it …} are printed immediately and therefore before printing the title, author etc. in \end{frontmatter}. So you cannot and should not use such hacks. If you use elsarticle, you should use it, as it is shown in the user manual of the class. If you don't like the result, don't use the class. BTW: \bf, \it etc. are obsolete. You should not use them any longer. Use, e.g. \textbf{…}, \textit{…} etc.

Another note unrelated to your question (but related to the shown code): elsarticle is a publisher class. When using it to submit an article to the publisher, you should not change the general layout, e.g., the margins.

Thanks for your advice and comment! I will pay attention to these matters！

The elsarticle class comes with a manual that has plenty of examples on how to type in the front matter.
You must follow the manual or your paper will be rejected.
You also shouldn't try and modify the layout. So no setting of \textheight and similar, nor setting to \baselinestretch.
I commented (and reorganized) your preamble: look at the comments, please.
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage{truetype}% what's this?
%\usepackage{latexsym}% obsolete
\usepackage{pifont,color,multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{times}% deprecated
%\usepackage{mwe}% useless
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphics}% not needed
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}  % loads »blindtext« and »graphicx«
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{inputenc}% useless
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{color}% useless with xcolor
\usepackage{,soul}
%\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}% use tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}% not along with subfig

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal Name}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}% why?

%\newcounter{myfn}[page]% what for?

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

% DON'T CHANGE THE PAGINATION PARAMETERS!
%\topmargin -0,75in \textheight 9,5 in
%\oddsidemargin -0.1in \textwidth 6.5in
%\evensidemargin -0.5in \footskip .5in

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}% what for?

%\def\Proof.{{\bf{Proof. }}}
%\def\End{\hspace{1cm} $\Box$\\}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}% what for?

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THE FOLLOWING ARE WRONG!
%\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
%\newfont{\bb}{msbm10 scaled\magstep1}
%\newcommand{\bN}{\mbox{\bb N}}
%\newcommand{\bZ}{\mbox{\bb Z}}
%\newcommand{\bQ}{\mbox{\bb Q}}
%\newcommand{\bR}{\mbox{\bb R}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frontmatter}
        
\title{Title of the paper}

\author[1]{Abigail Uthor\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}}
\ead{a.uthor@some.edu}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\author[2]{William Riter\fnref{fn1}}
\ead{w.riter@another.edu}

\author[3]{Sandra Cientist\fnref{fn2}}
\ead{s.cientist@whatever.edu}

\affiliation[1]{
  organization={Department of Mathematical Sciences, Some University},
}
\affiliation[2]{
  organization={Department of Mathematical Sciences, Another University},
}
\affiliation[3]{
  organization={Department of Mathematics and Statistics, University of Whatever},
}

\fntext[fn1]{Research was funded}
\fntext[fn2]{No fund for this research, unfortunately}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract of the paper
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Redundancy, Duplicate packages, Bad code
\end{keyword}
        
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

In this paper we want to prove the following important theorem.

\begin{theorem}
The fundamental property $0+0=0$ holds.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
This is obvious, ain't it?
\end{proof}
    
\end{document}



Thanks for your advice and help! It really works!
